# Constructing Nodejs HTTPS get Payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

currently I am trying to use the https.get function to retrieve tokens as well as make general API calls to Yahoo. I seem to be able to get it to work when I build a long query string and add it into the url, passing the whole url string as the first argument.

```
var finalUrl = host + path + "?" + paramString;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var data = {
       "error_str": "",
       "errno": 0,
       "return_code": 0,
       "contents": ""
    }
    console.log("In promise function");
    console.log("finalUrl: " + finalUrl);
var options = {
    "host": host,
    "path": path,
    "headers": params,
    "timeout": 2
};

console.log("options: " + JSON.stringify(options));

https.get(finalUrl, (res) => {
// resolves
```

However, when I try https.get with the options object so I can adjust the timeout for more data intensive calls, it fails

```
https.get(options, (res) => {
// rejects
```

Printing the final url yields:

finalUrl:

> https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key&oauth_nonce=334283&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_timestamp=1514728974491&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en-us&oauth_signature=my_comsumer_secret%26

Meanwhile, when I construct options it looks like this

```
{
    "host":"https://api.login.yahoo.com",
    "path":"/oauth/v2/get_request_token",
    "headers":{
        "xoauth_lang_pref":"en-us",     
        "oauth_callback": "oob",                  `                                                                                                          
        "oauth_consumer_key":"my_consumer_key",`
        "oauth_nonce":334283,
        "oauth_signature_method":"PLAINTEXT",
        "oauth_timestamp":1514728974491,
        "oauth_version":"1.0",
        "oauth_signature":"my_consumer_secret&"
    },
    "timeout":2
}
```

However, performing a get with this payload yields

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://api.login.yahoo.com https://api.login.yahoo.com:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two big problems with the way you're building the `options` object.

The first is that the `host` item is supposed to specify just the destination hostname, in this case `"api.login.yahoo.com"`. The `"https:"` part should be specified in a separate `protocol` item.  This is why you're getting the `ENOTFOUND` error.

The second is that the query string is supposed to be included as part of the `path` item.  So you should build the content of the `path` item just as you did when you constructed `finalUrl`.  The `headers` item is used for a completely different purpose.  It allows you to specify additional HTTP request headers, not query string elements.  You do not need a `headers` item here.

You can read all about the `options` items in the Node.js documentation at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback although most of the option items are irrelevant in this case.  You only need to use the `host`, `protocol` and `path` items.  That webpage will tell you why the `timeout` item you have right now is ineffective.